Execute automated tests based on changes in branch
currently I have an Android(Kotlin) and iOS(swift) App which uses XCUITest for IOS functional tests and CompuseUI for Android functional tests. As the codebase grows, so do our tests, I'm wondering if there's a sustainable approach to implementing a solution whereby we only run a specific set of tests e.g test plans in iOS or test suites in Android based on the files changed in a branch/PR?
I'm not familiar with the mobile ecosystem so wondering if there are any tools out there that already do this? if not what would be the best approach? For more context, we use CircleCi, git and Fastlane.

if you want to test your code and faster you may not want to use CircleCI because it can take a bit longer to run as it takes time to go from git to circleci may be you can set up a local server. for me I test my stuff on docker and some other stuff but you may just need to keep searching for a better testing plan. also can you see if you can help me I have this error in CircleCI I can not figure out Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv==2021.5.29 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pipenv==2021.5.29
